# How to best create an Octree/BVH in GPU memory without pointers?

Tags: gpu, hlsl, octree, boids

I've been working on a GPU-based boid simulation recently. I've spent most of my time trying to get the underlying sorting system working, in an attempt to avoid having each boid check every other boid—I'm ideally looking for this algorithm to end up being scalable into the hundreds of thousands of individual particles. However, I'm a bit confused as to how I should try to organize my boids into some kind of spatial tree structure when I don't have access to pointers (I'm working in HLSL).

I elected to try and base my method off of [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/thinking-parallel-part-iii-tree-construction-gpu/) incredibly helpful article. I already have a relatively quick radix sort functioning properly, but what I'm confused about is how I can actually put the sorted z-order morton keys to use. I naïvely assumed that, once sorted, all sequential boids would be sorted by distance, but this assumption breaks down whenever the boids are near the edge of two "sections" in the z-order curve, which causes some bizarre behavior that I've pictured below:

[image: bad boids!]

It seems clear that I also need to construct some kind of BVH (Bounding Volume Hierarchy) data structure so I can predictably access boids within a set distance, instead of just iterating over nearby sorted boids, but I'm stuck on how to achieve this in a language like HLSL that doesn't include pointers. I've read [this article](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems2/part-v-image-oriented-computing/chapter-37-octree-textures-gpu) a few times, but I'm not sure if it's well-suited to what I'm trying to do. Should I create nodes that store buffer indices instead of pointers? Or is there a simpler way that I could go about this?

I'd deeply appreciate any advice on how to move forward, thank you!